# Using Single Celery Server For Multi Django Projects

Tags: python, django, celery

I have 3 Separate Django Projects sharing same DB running on the same Machine.
What I require is to configure Celery For them.
Now my question is:

1.) Whether should I run separate celery daemons for separate projects, and set different vhosts and users in rabbitmq which I don't want to opt as it would be a waste of resources or

2.) Is there a way I can target all the tasks from different projects to a single celery server.

Also, How handy would  [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) be  in the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use same celery server to receive task from seperate projects.

Have a seperate celery app(or just a single file) say `foo` which has all tasks which are used in different projects.

```
# foo.py    
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y
```

Start a worker to run tasks

```
celery worker -l info -A foo
```

Now from Project A, you can call `add`

```
import celery

celery.current_app.send_task('foo.add', args=(1, 2))
```

And from Project B, you can call `sub`

```
import celery

celery.current_app.send_task('foo.sub', args=(1, 2))
```

You can use supervisord, to manage celery worker.

This approach might be slightly harder for testing as `send_task` won't respect `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER`. However you can use [this snippet](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/581#issuecomment-5687723) so that  `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` will be honored by `send_task`.

Comment: And how do Project A and Project B know about how to connect to the broker? Is there a piece missing, or do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe this was my [missing piece](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#main-name)